# HTML5 Canvas Variable Control in Flash

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, flash-cc

I'm using timeline animation and JavaScript in Flash to export an HTML5 canvas animation. The variables I declare at the start of the timeline are undefined when they're called at the end of the timeline. For instance:

```
var myCounter = 0; // frame 1



setTimeout(function(){
    if(myCounter < 1){
        exportRoot.play("replay");
    } else{this.stop();}
},5000); // located in last frame
```

Why is `myCounter` undefined in the last frame? I'm trying to loop this several times. Also, where can I find methods to use for this since traditional JavaScript doesn't seem to always work (maybe it's me)?

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix your variables with `this.` so that they stay accessible throughout the animation.

```
this.myCounter = 0; // frame 1
setTimeout(function(){
    if(this.myCounter < 1){
        exportRoot.play("replay");
    } else{this.stop();}
},5000); // located in last frame
```